# lights are crushing the textures

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, materials, lighting

My lighting is crushing the texture. I tried to use "Use Nodes" but nothing changes. the texture feels present in default HDRIs but not in scene lighting.

with scene lights:

[image]

with default HDRI:

[image]

What is going wrong here and how can I fix it?

Here is the link to file:
[image]

Comment: Can anyone answer this question? please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

increase the roughness of the material.